# Error in pagination results

Tags: php, pagination

I have this code for pagination on my php script

```
<?php
session_start();
//Database stuff here
$image = $_SESSION['image'];
$cat = $_GET['cate'];
$pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];
//PAGING BEGINS
if(!isset($pagenum)){
    $pagenum = 1;
}

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE category = '$cat'");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($data);
$page_rows = 4;
$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);

if($pagenum < 1)
    $pagenum = 1;
elseif($pagenum > $last)
    $pagenum = $last;

$max = 'limit '.($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows.','.$page_rows;
$data_p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE category = '$cat' $max");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data_p)) {
    echo $row[1];
    echo $row[2];
}

echo "<p>";
echo "--Page $pagenum of Last </p>";

if($pagenum == 1){
} else {
    echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'>First</a>";
    echo "";
    $previous = $pagenum - 1;
    echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$previous'><-Previous</a>";
}

if($pagenum == $last){
} else {
    $next = $pagenum + 1;
    echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'>Next ->></a>";
    echo "";
    echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'>Last</a>";
}
?>
```

When i run it, the first page is shown with 4 items as specified but when i click "Next", the $pagenum variable becomes 0, causing a negative range in the limit($max) and hence an SQL error. I have no idea why. I've tried several paging scripts and have ended up with thesame error. $pagenum becomes 0 when i try to move to the next page. Please what is my mistake? Thanks

Comment: What is `$rows` equal to? FYI, mysql_* functions shouldn't be used and you are susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: This is really a bad piece of code... Still horrifying how people are developing even these days...

Comment: @Pitchinnate $rows = 15 when i run it. But becomes 0 when i click NEXT.

Comment: This code is very strange and bad written. Try to get in touch with the language. Something like this is basic stuff: `if($pagenum == $last){
} else {` You should use the `!==` operator instead. In addition to that you should not use mysql_* function since they are deprecated now. Even these linebreaks(?) with an empty `echo "";` is terrible. And I could point out much more... Try to learn PHP 'correctly'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think I know the problem, you have:

```
echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'>Last</a>";
```

Problem is probably that `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` returns index.php you are then adding on `?pagenum=1` therefore your resulting url is:

/index.php?pagenum=1

So you are losing your category variable. Try changing all links to something like this:

```
echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last&cate=$cat'>Last</a>";
```

Comment: Not sure if it is suppose to be `cate` but that is what you have in your code, not sure if that is a typo or not. But this is why rows goes to 0 after you go to a link.